# 3-е склонение / 3 склонение

Tags: орфография

Нужно ли наращение в этом случае?

`Как склонять русские существительные, которые являются частью 3-го / 3 склонения, и что такое 3-е / 3 склонение?`

Comment: А какие у вас сомнения,  ведь числительные порядковые?  Или вы думаете иначе?  В русском языке 3 (три) склонения, и одно из них называется 3-м склонением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь порядковое числительное, поэтому наращение нужно:

***Как склонять русские существительные, которые являются частью 3-го склонения, и что такое 3-е склонение?***